# connecting to pluggable database using administrator user

Tags: oracle

I have a question about connecting to pluggable database using a user(scott/tiger).Lets say,I am connected as

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Then I want to open my pluggable database:

```
alter pluggable database ORC open;
```

And then,I want to connect as user scott to my pluggable db (ORC) using this:

```
connect scott/tiger@ORC;
```

However,I got this error:
ORA-01031(INSUFFICIENT PRIVILEGES).

My question is should I have made scott as my administrator user while creating this pluggable db in order for scott to connect to this pdb?

Some help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably user scott does not have *CONNECT* or *CREATE SESSION* privileges.

Regardless, you can effectively connect to a PDB from sqlplus by issuing

```
alter session set container = PDB_NAME;
```

Example:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> select name, open_mode from v$containers;
NAME                           OPEN_MODE
------------------------------ ----------
CDB$ROOT                       READ WRITE
PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY
...........
TEST12C                        MOUNTED
TESTCAT                        READ WRITE

7 rows selected.

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT

SQL> alter session set container = TESTCAT;
Session altered.

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
TESTCAT
```

Also check the official documentation:

[Administering a CDB with SQL*Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_admin.htm#ADMIN13607)

[Viewing Information About CDBs and PDBs with SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_mon.htm#ADMIN13719)